# Careers mistakenly says I don't have commits to GitHub repository opencv-contrib

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, error-message

I definitely have commits. You can verify that by going to the [OpenCV changelog](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog) and searching for "Marc-Stefan Cassola" there.

Maybe that is because of the vast amount of contributors or commits?

Comment: Having the same issue with different project, very disappointed